# Error "Invalid UTF-8" when compiling sass with @import

Tags: css, sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

There's my project with the folowing structire:

```
project
  assets
    scripts
    styles
      app.scss
  bower_components
  node_modules
  public
    css
      app.css
    js
  bower.json
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
```

I use gulp-sass to compile app.scss to app.css and i want to include foundation in app.scss

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.src.styles)
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: ['./bower_components/foundation/scss']
    }))
    .pipe(concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.public.styles));
})
```

Then I white in app.scss file:

```
@import 'foundation/_settings';
@import 'foundation';
```

And when i run gulp, I get:

```
Error: assets\styles\app.scss
  undefined:undefined  Invalid UTF-8
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Check if you have any random characters anywhere like in file paths, inside scss files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a UNIX unsupported letter in your folder path ? Try removing it.

I removed this error by removing the letter "ä" from the folder name.

Comment: Should I take into account the entire path from hard drive? I'm asking because I have Russian user name

Comment: just check the name whether there is special characters or not like i mentioned above `"ä"`

Comment: I have no such char's anywhere in my system :p as far as I know. Running node-sass: 3.12.5 and still i get this :O

Answer (score 1):

set file encoding to UTF-8 in your IDE, it is probably something else by default and sass is interprets it as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I just had to rename windows user name, because it contained UNIX unsupported characters. 
But because it was too difficult to rename the folder of user, I just moved my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace on package.json of gulp-sass, instead of
`"node-sass": "^3.4.2"`
with
`"node-sass": "^3.5.0-beta.1"`

This worked for me!