# Internal Error: Invalid UTF-8 - Sass & Gulp

Tags: javascript, css, utf-8, sass, gulp

I get the following error when trying to run `gulp sass` in Linux Ubuntu

```
hutber@hutber-ubuntu:/var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk$ gulp sass
[14:43:26] Using gulpfile /var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk/gulpfile.js
[14:43:26] Starting 'sass'...
[14:43:27] gulp-notify: [Compile Error] frontend/sass/style.scss
Internal Error: Invalid UTF-8

[14:43:27] Finished 'sass' after 547 ms
```

Searching through all the files/folders for any special characters returns nothing.

```
hutber@hutber-ubuntu:/var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk$ find ./* -iregex '.*/.*[èö].*' -print
```

Otherwise if I remove the @import at the start of the file it will then fail on the @include border-box-sizing; as this is a variable from `susy`

So of course how can I get sass running locally?

**updated**

```
hutber@hutber-ubuntu:/var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk/frontend/sass$ find ./* | xargs grep -i '.*/.*[èö].*'
grep: ./fonts: Is a directory
grep: ./fonts/helvetica-neue: Is a directory
grep: ./modules: Is a directory
grep: ./modules/form: Is a directory
grep: ./pages: Is a directory
grep: ./plugins: Is a directory
grep: ./susy: Is a directory
grep: ./susy/susy: Is a directory
grep: ./susy/susy/language: Is a directory
grep: ./susy/susy/language/susy: Is a directory
grep: ./susy/susy/language/susyone: Is a directory
grep: ./susy/susy/su: Is a directory
grep: ./susy/susy/output: Is a directory
grep: ./susy/susy/output/support: Is a directory
grep: ./susy/susy/output/float: Is a directory
grep: ./susy/susy/output/shared: Is a directory
```

NB: Similar Question: [Error "Invalid UTF-8" when compiling sass with @import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496807/error-invalid-utf-8-when-compiling-sass-with-import) 
This is fixed by removing special charaters from the path, however all my folders are english and always have been.

Comment: try opening the css file in binary mode with 'vi -b' and then execute 'set list' to show non printable characters. Besides, your find command is searching on file names not on content, try this: find ./* | xargs grep -i '.*/.*[èö].*'

Comment: Cheers Luis, well set list didn't show up anything usual I don't believe. `^I^Itoggle: top right,^M$` for example. Lots of `^I`'s and `^M$`.
I'll update question with new find :)

Comment: What about the css contents? any non ascii characters there?

Comment: You can try converting the file to ASCII and see if ? marks appears, those are the non UTF-8 ones: cat your-file.css | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT > ascii.css

Comment: No question marks:
`hutber@hutber-ubuntu:/var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk/frontend/sass$ cat ascii.css | grep ?
hutber@hutber-ubuntu:/var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk/frontend/sass$ `
I think I need to convert all css files :O

Comment: ? is an special character for grep, try grep '\?' ascii.css, do not forget single quotes. Also, you can inspect the file visually if it's not too big.

Comment: You beautiful helpful man! I found the problem, it wasn't in my file but a plugin I was using:
/*!
 * Pikaday
 * Copyright � 2014 David Bushell | BSD & MIT license | http://dbushell.com/
 */
As you can see the ? I used the grep fix on the compiled css and it showed up. Then it was just a case of trouble shooting it back down. If you want to answer I will accept.  Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128370/discussion-between-luis-munoz-and-jamie-hutber).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try converting the file to ASCII and see if ? marks appears, those are the non UTF-8 ones:

```
cat your-file.css | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT > ascii.css
```